# What can be the reason of getting segfault in my C code?

Tags: c

I am breaking my head of the reason why I am getting segfault when I do queue_arr[i] = queue_create(), everything seem to be okay.. I checked with debugger that queue_create() returns actual queue. Memory is allocated for a new queue.. Not sure what can be the reason! Need help.

Here is snippet of the code in main:

```
queue_t **queue_arr;
global_array_of_queues = queue_arr;
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < number_of_categories; i++){
    queue_arr[i] = queue_create(); //<<<------!!! segfault here
}
```

here is the function:

```
queue_t *queue_create() {
    queue_t *new_queue = calloc(1, sizeof(queue_t));
    if (new_queue == NULL){
        perror("calloc failed to allocate memory. \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&new_queue->mutex, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_mutex_init failed. \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (pthread_cond_init(&new_queue->wait_for_not_empty_queue, NULL) != 0) {
        /* signal for our consumers */
        perror("pthread_cond_init failed. \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (pthread_cond_init(&new_queue->wait_for_empty_queue, NULL) != 0) {
        /* signal for our producer */
        perror("pthread_cond_init failed. \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    new_queue->category = NULL;
    new_queue->rear = NULL;

    return new_queue;
}
```

queue type:

```
typedef struct queue {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t wait_for_not_empty_queue;
    pthread_cond_t wait_for_empty_queue;
    char *category;
    struct queue_node *rear;
} queue_t;
```

not sure if it affect something but I also declare global pointer to my queue:

```
extern queue_t **global_array_of_queues;
```

[image]

Comment: `queue_arr` doesn't point anywhere valid, let alone `queue_arr[i]`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you initialize `queue_arr` itself.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `queue_arr` to point to. Right now it's uninitialized, so dereferencing it is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

*queue_arr* is not initialized. You need to reserve memory on the heap before you go into the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your `queue_arr` is not allocated, so assigning `queue_arr[i]` you are violating the memory.